# How to reference another in a reference in excel?

Tags: excel, reference

I have some values and they are numbered 0-25, from A-Z. I have a cell with a value A-Z, and I want to use this value in an equation for another cell: `=COLUMN('Cell Value'1)`. I tried using `CELL("contents",A3)` which is the reference to the letter. I want it to be where it automatically changes the column reference when the letter changes. If there is a way to do this that I couldn't find then please help.

Comment: =INDEX(A1..Z26,row,col) might do what you want. XL always indexes from 1 and from A. Or alternatively =INDIRECT(value) which might also be what you have asked for. See MS [Help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a text string to a part of a cell reference using `INDIRECT()`.

In this example `INDIRECT(A2&1)` will return value of B1 if A2 contains `"B"`, C1 if A2 contain `"С"` and so on.

[image: INDIRECT() text to cell address]

Comment: How can I make this work with two letters? Like `=INDIRECT(A&A2&3)`. It is a double letter but I don't want to make the text in the referenced cell to be a double. Like the referenced cell has C in it but I want to get the value of the now `AC1`, or if it has E, `AE1`.

Comment: I got it working, thanks!